# Factorize certain polynomials as product of irreducibles

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I'm trying to solve this question from my abstract algebra's course. I know it's a very trivial question that can be solved using Ruffini like we are taught before college, but my question is how can I solve it using "ring of polynomial" theory. The question goes like this:

> Factorize the following polynomials as product of irreducibles:
>
> 1. $X^5 − 2X^4 − 12X + 24$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$
> 2. $X^4+X^2+1$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[X]$

I know about ring theory and some ring of polynomials theory, but I don't see what can I do here to approach this kind of problem using abstract algebra methods (instead of Ruffini, because I guess I'm not supposed to solve it that way after all the theory I've studied, where this method is never introduced). How can I solve this? Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $2$  is an obvious root of $P(X)=X^5 − 2X^4 − 12X + 24$, hence $P(X)=(X-2)Q(X)$. Try to apply Eisenstein Criterion to $Q(X)$.
2. $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ has characteristic $2$, hence $\mathbf Z[X]$ too, so that $x\mapsto x^2$ is a ring homomorphism (the *Frobenius homomorphism*).

Comment: Oh, I didn't thought about using eisenstein criterion. I'll take it a look, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Also, how is it obvious that in the polynomial 1) $2$ is a root. I mean, I know it's a root, but how can I justify that I know it without just trying and seeing that evaluating in $2$ gives $0$.

Comment: I found $Q(X)=X^4-12$, and using Eisenstein criterion, I conclude $Q(X)$ is irreducible because $3$ is prime and $3\mid 12$ but $3^2\nmid 12$. Am I right?

Comment: An integer root is a divisor of the constant term, so I tested first the prime divisors of $24$, and the first tested was indeed  a root, that's all.

Comment: That's exactly how I reasoned (adding $3$ doesn't divide the leading coefficient).

Comment: Nice, I totally understood the first one. I'm still trying to figure out the second one... I'm not familiarized with the characteristic concept.

Comment: In such rings, $2=0$, and in the binomial expansion the coefficient of $xy$ is $2$, so $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2$ – you have similar results for arbitrary characteristic.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

In view of $GF(2)[x]$ with $GF(2) = \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, the irreducible polynomials of degree at most 4 are

$x,x+1,x^2+x+1,x^3+x+1,x^3+x^2+1, x^4+x+1, x^4+x^3+1, x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.

This should suffice to factorize $x^4+x^2+1$ which is reducible.